# angular-datatables rendering (repeating) twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatables https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables and noticed that the ng-repeat is done twice. I noticed it with the following directive.

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in vm.orders track by order.id" repeatlogger>

app.directive('repeatlogger', function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.$index);
}
```

I am using the Angular way, see HTML tab at https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay

```
<table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in vm.persons  | limitTo: 50" repeatlogger>
            <td>{{ person.ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.Firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.Lastname }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using a ng-repeat on a div shows that it iterates once over the collection.

Which reasons exist, that angular-datatables iterates twice over the collection?

Comment: How many items where there in the data source of angular-datatable ?

Comment: perhaps you have `datatable=""` in the markup? If you have so, both angular and dataTables will render the rows.

Comment: You should elaborate in the question itself, not create answers for that.  Click [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39127688/edit) and delete the answer below. As I mention above `ng-repeat` is not called twice, when you have `datatable=""` **AND** you have a `ng-repeat` then both the `ng-repeat` and dataTables' own rendering will be executed. It is what you are telling your app to do, it does exactly as expected.

Comment: On my opinion, with datatable="" and ng-repeat, I only see a one time rendering. Also pagination is broke, it shows only one page.

Comment: +1 for elaborating :) `datatable=""` means that dataTables render the table itself. You have added an extra unnecessary  `ng-repeat` ....How should dataTables stop the `ng-repeat`, or even be aware of it ..? You did NOT have `datatable="ng"` in the deleted answer where you repeted your code (I can see that) You can use this plnkr as a starting point -> http://plnkr.co/edit/nBtzURQxSgKIqFvGMkWC?p=preview if you want to demonstrate your code in action...